# Некорректный HSV у OpenCV для Python

Tags: python, opencv, color, перевод

Использую код из [документации](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) OpenCV для Python для перевода зеленого цвета палитры RGB в HSV

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
hsv_green = cv.cvtColor(green,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv_green)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю вывод, прямо как в документации. Вот только при попытке перевести этот цвет обратно в таблицу RGB, не пользуясь средствами OpenCV, получается желтый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сталкивался ли кто-то с такой же проблемой? Есть ли сторонние утилиты, позволяющие подобрать нужный диапазон для выделения объекта по цвету в OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в приведении диапазона значений.

Значение цветового оттенка `H` в HSV модели имеет диапазон `0..360` градусов, а в байтовый формат OpenCV такое число не влезет, поэтому оно делится пополам, как указано в приведенной ссылке:

```
 8-bit images: V←255V,S←255S,H←H/2(to fit to 0 to 255)
```

Зелёный соответствует 120 градусов или 60 единиц в 8-битном формате OpenCV.

Чтобы использовать полученное в OpenCV значение там, где нужен 360-градусный диапазон, умножьте значение на два.

Заметьте, что подобные проблемы могут встретиться и для яркости и насыщенности - где-то используется диапазон `0.0..1.0`, где-то `0..255` или `0..100%`. Рисунок во вашей ссылке отображает 255% - видимо, там нужно для зеленого вводить `120 градусов, 100%, 100%`